# gnome-terminal --tab opens a window in Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, gnome-terminal, tabs

On my laptop (Xubuntu 18.04) in the gnome-terminal the commands

```
gnome-terminal
gnome-terminal --tab
```

both open a new tab.

On my desktop (Xubuntu 16.04) they both open a new window. Changing the option "Open new terminals in Tab/Window" under "Edit > Preferences > General" does not affect the behavior (on the desktop). I want to open tabs, what to do?

Comment: Yes I know but I have it as a makefile command that opens all my stuff. Thanks anyway:)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using Xubuntu's default terminal?

Comment: And could you edit your question to post the output of `ls -l ~/.config/dconf/user`?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, file a bug report. If you set `Open new terminals in Tab` in `Preferences` you should be able to open a new tab in the current window by choosing `Files > Open Terminal`. Remind that  different versions of gnome-terminal are installed in your systems.

Comment: See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/issues/127.

Comment: Opening a new tab this way didn't work in 16.04. The `--tab` command line option is for opening multiple new terminals at the same time, that are tabs of a single window, rather than separate windows. The version in 18.04 addressed this not really user friendly behavior it to some extent.